# Calling typescript interface from commonJS function call

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code sample in ts AuthorityProvider is an interface its implemented on the library like this

```
export interface AuthorityProvider {
     /** Get subset of `availableKeys` needed to meet authorities in `transaction` */
    getRequiredKeys: (args: AuthorityProviderArgs) => Promise<string[]>;
}
```

TScode

```
const authorityProvider: AuthorityProvider = {
  getRequiredKeys: (args: AuthorityProviderArgs): Promise<string[]> => {
    return Promise.resolve([accountPublicKey])
  },
}
```

I tried to recode this on CommonJS but no luck please advice 
this is my code

```
const authorityProvider = ( getRequiredKeys => {  
  return Promise.resolve([accountPublicKey]) 
})
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the TS console ?

Comment: I am not trying out a ts script I want to convert the ts code to commonJS